# Search API module causes server error when saving index fields

Tags: entities, search, debugging

I am very new to Drupal, so please let me know if I'm doing something wrong.

Using the Search API module, I would like to go change some fields of my Node Index. For example, I would like to uncheck the "Title" field so it is no longer indexed for searching. However, the problem arises when I try to save this or any other change to the fields. I get an error page saying "Your browser sent a request that this server rejected, possibly due to security scanner restrictions." and the fields remain unchanged.

Similar posts have given me the sense that the fix may be to uninstall/reinstall the module. But this module is so fundamental to everything I've been doing over the last few days. If I uninstall/reinstall the module, will it erase everything I've done?

**Update**: I disabled the server and then enabled it and now the index fields are working (yay) but it deleted my search (boo)

Answer (score 0):

After you disable a module (not 'server' ... as in the "update" part of the question ...) and then enable it again, problems like these might get resolved. There are other situations (and modules) where some similar issues occur, and then get resolved via such disable/enable.

To avoid loosing data (like your search that got deleted), this is a possible approach you may want to consider:

- look at the module's `.install) file to find out which table it created (during install).
- perform a backup of the tables that are mentioned in the `.install` file (before uninstalling the module.
- disable the module, which will also perform the steps you can see within the .install file (for uninstall now) and then enable the module again.
- restore your backup of your tables related to the module.